# Android TV does not support my App. Can't see my TV app in TV Play Store. Whats Wrong with my Manifest?

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, android-tv

I built my App using Cordova. When releasing it in Google play Console, it says that TVs are compatible (806  TV devices compatible).

But after all, my App is not visible in TV's Play Store. I am using 2 DIFFERENT android TVS (XIaomi MI tv Stick, Android 9) and (bTV, Android 9).

This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:versionCode="10004" android:versionName="1.0.4" package="com.eyecharts.div" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:banner="@drawable/banner" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:exported="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please, Whats Wrong with my Manifest?
NOTE: I added the following in cordova config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
```

Comment: Did you opt in to TV distribution in the Play Console? It's under Settings -> Advanced settings -> Release types -> "+ Add release type"